# operator.itemgetter(*item) giving error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: sorting, python-3.9

I am using a recursive function for Grouping data list which I am getting by executing database query and the below function worked fine. But since yesterday it started throwing error as below:

in _group_data data_list.sort(key=itemgetter(*filter_key))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

```
def _group_data(data_list, key_list, previous_key=[]):
    """
    :param data_list: A list of dictionary got from executing sql query.
    :param key_list: Group by list of keys.
    :param previous_key: The earlier key to do grouping at the root level. Default is an empty list.
    :return: Grouped Data list.
    """
    
    # Base case
    if len(key_list) == 1:
        filter_key = key_list[0]
        data_list.sort(key=itemgetter(*filter_key))
        dl = list()
        for _, group in groupby(data_list, key=itemgetter(*filter_key)):
            d_dict = {'details': []}
            for g in group:
                if previous_key is not None:
                    d_dict['details'].append(
                        {key: value for key, value in g.items() if key not in (filter_key + previous_key)}
                    )
                    d_dict.update({key: value for key, value in g.items() if key in filter_key})
                else:
                    d_dict['details'].append({key: value for key, value in g.items() if key not in filter_key})
                    d_dict.update({key: value for key, value in g.items() if key in filter_key})
            dl.append(d_dict)
        return dl
    # Recursive block
    else:
        filter_key = key_list[0]
        dl = list()
        p_key = previous_key + filter_key
        data_list.sort(key=itemgetter(*filter_key)) #getting error here
        for _, group in groupby(data_list, key=itemgetter(*filter_key)):
            group_list = list(group)
            print('key_list[1:] ',key_list[1:])
            print('p_key ',p_key)
            d_list = _group_data(group_list, key_list[1:], p_key)
            p_dict = {key: value for key, value in group_list[0].items() if key in filter_key}
            p_dict['details'] = d_list
            dl.append(p_dict)
        return dl
```

I am trying to Identify the problem but not getting any clue, Also tried few things from the google search but nothing helped for example sorted() but got the same error. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved. I was getting data as null for a key, but it was supposed to be integer that's why it was throwing error. so, from the dB side value of that key is set to 0 as a default.